# Method that return a query from a query in argument

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, reflection

### Presentation

I have a `ContactProfileModel` entity class with some properties :

- FirstName
- LastName
- BirthDate etc..

I have other Entities who have a `ContactProfileModel` foreignkey. Example : `RegistrationModel.Contact`.

### Needs

I would like to create a method whith the Following signature :

```
public static Expression<Func<TModel, string>> Contact<TModel>(Expression<Func<TModel, ContactProfileModel>> contact)
```

And use it this way :

```
DisplayQuery.Contact<RegistrationModel>(m => m.ContactProfile))
```

As an equivalent of

```
m => m.ContactProfile.FirstName + " " + m.ContactProfile.FirstName + " " + m.ContactProfile.BirthDate.ToShortTimeString()
```

### Objective

The objective is to return a linq query where result is a string and contains different informations of the contact. Example : "John Doe (10/10/90)"

### Note

I have discussed with some people who told me to use `Expression.Call` and `Expression.Property` but unfortunatly I do not have enough knowledge to use it properly.

Here I expose my problem without extra details, but I have my reasons to create my method only this way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a full working implementation: the code runs and outputs what you'd expect.

I'm slightly short on time, so I'm going to leave it as this. If you want clarification, ask in the comments and I'll do my best to answer.

```
public class Program
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo stringConcatMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Concat", new[] { typeof(string[]) });
    private static readonly MethodInfo toShortTimeStringMethod = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("ToShortTimeString");
    private static readonly PropertyInfo firstNameProperty = typeof(ContactProfileModel).GetProperty("FirstName");
    private static readonly PropertyInfo lastNameProperty = typeof(ContactProfileModel).GetProperty("LastName");
    private static readonly PropertyInfo birthDateProperty = typeof(ContactProfileModel).GetProperty("BirthDate");

    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = Contact<RegistrationModel>(x => x.ContactProfile);

        // Test it
        var model = new RegistrationModel()
        {
            ContactProfile = new ContactProfileModel()
            {
                FirstName = "First",
                LastName = "Last",
                BirthDate = DateTime.Now,
            }
        };
        var str = result.Compile()(model);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TModel, string>> Contact<TModel>(Expression<Func<TModel, ContactProfileModel>> contact)
    {
        // We've been given a LambdaExpression. It's got a single
        // parameter, which is the 'x' above, and its body
        // should be a MemberExpression accessing a property on
        // 'x' (you might want to check this and throw a suitable
        // exception if this isn't the case). We'll grab the
        // body of the LambdaExpression, and use that as the
        // 'm.ContactProfile' expression in your question. 
        // At the end, we'll construct a new LambdaExpression
        // with our body. We need to use the same ParameterExpression
        // given in this LambdaExpression.
        var modelParameter = contact.Parameters[0];
        var propertyAccess = (MemberExpression)contact.Body;

        // <contact>.FirstName
        var firstNameAccess = Expression.Property(propertyAccess, firstNameProperty);
        // <contact>.LastName
        var lastNameAccess = Expression.Property(propertyAccess, lastNameProperty);
        // <contact>.BirthDate
        var birthDateAccess = Expression.Property(propertyAccess, birthDateProperty);
        // <contact>.BirthDate.ToShortTimeString()
        var birthDateShortTimeStringCall = Expression.Call(birthDateAccess, toShortTimeStringMethod);

        // string.Concat(new string[] { <contact>.FirstName, " ", etc }
        var argsArray = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(string), new Expression[]
        {
            firstNameAccess,
            Expression.Constant(" "),
            lastNameAccess,
            Expression.Constant(" "),
            birthDateShortTimeStringCall
        });
        var concatCall = Expression.Call(stringConcatMethod, argsArray);

        // Turn it all into a LambdaExpression
        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, string>>(concatCall, modelParameter);
        // Note: if you inspect 'result.DebugView' in a debugger at this 
        // point, you'll see a representation of the expression we've built
        // up above, which is useful for figuring out where things have gone
        // wrong.
        return result;
    }
}

public class ContactProfileModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class RegistrationModel
{
    public ContactProfileModel ContactProfile { get; set; }
}
```

It might be that EF doesn't like the call to `String.Concat` - in that case, you might have to use a set of `Expression.Add` calls there instead.

Comment: Thanks you for you very well explained solution. It helped me a lot to see how to handle the Expression module to produce that what I needed, and I can tell you that Concat is accepted in a 'LINQ to SQL' query.

Answer (score 0):

First answer on StackOverflow, so be kind ;)

I tried to solve the problem, but expressions are not easy to work with. Thanks canton7 for the answer. I edited my answer in order to show the solution if you want to use the `.ToString()` method in expressions.

```
public class ContactProfileModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{FirstName} {LastName} {BirthDate.ToShortDateString()}";
    }
}

public class RegistrationModel
{
    public ContactProfileModel ContactProfile { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var registration = new RegistrationModel
        {
            ContactProfile = new ContactProfileModel
            {
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe",
                BirthDate = DateTime.Now
            }
        };

        var expression = Contact<RegistrationModel>(m => m.ContactProfile);

        Console.WriteLine(expression.Compile()(registration));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TModel, string>> Contact<TModel>(Expression<Func<TModel, ContactProfileModel>> contact)
    {
        var propertyAccess = (MemberExpression)contact.Body;
        var toString = typeof(ContactProfileModel).GetMethod("ToString");
        var toStringValue = Expression.Call(propertyAccess, toString);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TModel, string>>(toStringValue, contact.Parameters[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well.. no I can't, because I need to return a `Expression<Func<TModel, string>>` and not a `string` directly. But anyway thanks for your first contribution :)

Comment: The potential problem here (with your edit) is that Entity Framework is going to take this expression and turn it into SQL (I'm assuming, from the entity-framework tag in the question). That SQL won't have access to the C# implementation of ToString (and even if it did, it wouldn't be able to turn that C# code into SQL).

Comment: You are probably right, I tested my code, but not with Entity Framework. It will probably work, but likely ToString will not be evaluated on the database.